# Import this class in MVEL and assign values to its property and access its method

Tags: mvel

I have a math class in a package `mypackage`.
Now I want to import this class in MVEL and assign values to its property and access its method.
I have written the following code but its giving error as

```
Exception in thread "main" [Error: unknown class or illegal statement: 
                      ^
```

Code is

```
ParserContext context = new ParserContext();
context.addImport("math",mypackage.MyMaths.class);//MyMaths.class is public
context.addInput("obj", mypackage.MyMaths.class);

String expression1 = "obj.a == 20";//a is public property

Serializable compiled1 = MVEL.compileExpression(expression1,context);

MVEL.executeExpression(compiled1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below approach.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map map = new HashMap();
        MyMaths mayMaths = new MyMaths();
        map.put("obj", mayMaths);

        String expression1 = "obj.a = 20";

        Serializable compiled1 = MVEL.compileExpression(expression1);

        MVEL.executeExpression(compiled1, map);

        System.out.println(mayMaths.getA());
    }
```

Output - 20